# SAP Gateway Client throws PAGE NOT FOUND! while creating OData service

Tags: odata, sap-gateway

I have been working on S/4 Hana. I was creating a odata service using existing BAPI `BAPI_SALESORDER_GETLIST`.

1. I selected the required data while importing the RFC and set Customer number as the key.
2. I have taken Customer, Sales Organization and Doc Date as input

Then while Mapping for the key there was no output so i put a dummy output as shown in the

[image]

Otherwise it was showing error that there is no output for the input key Customer Number.

3. After registering and activating it , then i went to SAP GATEWAY CLIENT to execute the URI `/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZINFORMED_ENTRY_SRV/metadata` but after executing it shows

[image: screenshot]

4. I have also checked the transaction `/IWFND/ERROR_LOG` there it is showing in ERROR INFO: The URI or metadata definition is incorrect.

I'll be very thankful to you if you can help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try loading this one:
/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZINFORMED_ENTRY_SRV/$metadata
Since the current implementation supports ODatav2 the $ has to be there. See also:
http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview/#ServiceMetadataDocument